# Deploy acodos generatec code to cpp using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, build, code-generation

## Goal

I want to create a controller in .cpp to control a simple pendulum using acados, to learn how to use it for real controllers.

## Problem

How do you include the generated code from acados in a .cpp program. That is:

1. What header files you have to include?
2. How do you build your project with CMake?

## What i have done so far:

### Generate c files and a CmakeList.

I have created some code in acados to solve an OPC. It works, and using the AcadosSim i simulate the pendulum.  I can generate the c files from the python interface with:

```py
builder = CMakeBuilder()
ocp_solver = AcadosOcpSolver(ocp, json_file = 'acados_ocp.json')
ocp_solver.generate(ocp,cmake_builder=builder)
```

And a folder `c_generated_code` is created with a `CMakeLists.txt`.

### Make

If i do:

```bash
cd c_generated_code
make
```

i get some `main_pendulum` and `main_sim_pendulum` executables which i can run and they work. So code_generation seems to work without a problem.

### CMake

If i enable some options in this `CMakeLists.txt`, i generate some executables that run correctly if i have sourced the acados relevant environmental variables:

```bash
export ACADOS_SOURCE_DIR="$HOME/acados"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$HOME/acados/lib"
```

- More info for this below in the python-created-Cmake output section.
- Building the executables doesn't required sourcing the above variables.

### Modify .cpp

If i try to include this header file:

```cpp
#include "c_generated_code/acados_solver_pendulum.h"
```

and modify the `CMakeLists.txt` of the c code like this:

```
export(TARGETS acados_ocp_solver_pendulum FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/acados_ocp_solver_pendulumConfig.cmake)
```

and the root `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
add_subdirectory(c_generated_code)

find_package(acados_ocp_solver_pendulum REQUIRED PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
target_link_libraries(passive_simulation  acados_ocp_solver_pendulum #other_libs)
```

But i still get this error:

```
fatal error: 'acados/utils/types.h' file not found
```

## Extra

### python-created-Cmake output:

I get the following output if use the `CMakeLists.txt` generated by the python interface.

```bash
Scanning dependencies of target ocp_pendulum
[ ... ] to avoid cluttering i do not show these
[ 55%] Building C object CMakeFiles/ocp_pendulum.dir/acados_solver_pendulum.c.o
[ 55%] Built target ocp_pendulum
Scanning dependencies of target model_pendulum
[ 72%] Building C object CMakeFiles/model_pendulum.dir/pendulum_model/pendulum_impl_dae_jac_x_xdot_u_z.c.o
[ 72%] Built target model_pendulum
Scanning dependencies of target sim_pendulum
[ 77%] Building C object CMakeFiles/sim_pendulum.dir/acados_sim_solver_pendulum.c.o
[ 77%] Built target sim_pendulum
Scanning dependencies of target main_pendulum
[ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main_pendulum.dir/main_pendulum.c.o
[ 88%] Linking C executable main_pendulum
[ 88%] Built target main_pendulum
Scanning dependencies of target acados_solver_pendulum
[ 94%] Linking C shared library libacados_solver_pendulum.so
[ 94%] Built target acados_solver_pendulum
Scanning dependencies of target acados_ocp_solver_pendulum
[100%] Linking C shared library libacados_ocp_solver_pendulum.so
[100%] Built target acados_ocp_solver_pendulum
```

Building succeeds!

### Directory structure:

My directory structure is like that:

```
.
├── acados_ocp.json
├── acados_ocp_nlp.json
├── build
│   ├── #some files
├── c_generated_code
│   ├── acados_sim_solver_pendulum.c
│   ├── acados_sim_solver_pendulum.h
│   ├── acados_solver_pendulum.c
│   ├── acados_solver_pendulum.h
│   ├── acados_solver_pendulum.o
│   ├── acados_solver.pxd
│   ├── build
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── libacados_ocp_solver_pendulum.so
│   ├── main_pendulum.c
│   ├── main_sim_pendulum.c
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── pendulum_constraints
│   ├── pendulum_cost
│   └── pendulum_model
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── passive_simulation.cc
├── pendulum_model.py
├── pendulum_ocp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your compiler is unable to locate Acados parent directory.
Since this problem persists despite using the following command:

```
export ACADOS_SOURCE_DIR="$HOME/acados"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$HOME/acados/lib"
```

, the reason might be because your compiler is configured in a separate environment than, for example, your .bashrc file (this is a common issue while using WSL).

I know this post is a bit old, but for any future reference this answer might be helpful

One workaround is by adding `include_directories("/path/to/acados")` to your CMakeLists.txt file and the reloading it.